# Flash of protected route's content with React Router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When using [React Router 6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) to create a "protected route", I see the protected page's content flash briefly before the redirect to the login page.

I would assume this must be a well-known problem. Is there a solution to this?

ProtectedRoute:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
    redirectPath = '/login',
    children
}) => {

    const { user } = UserAuth();

    if (!user) {
        return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
    }

    return children
        ? children
        : <Outlet />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

AppRouter:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
    <Routes>

        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginPage />}/>

        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />} >
            <Route path="account" element={<AccountPage />} />
        </Route>

    </Routes>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

The issue is that to provide proper UI/UX to the user you need 3 states (*i.e. authenticated, unauthenticated, indeterminant*) instead of 2 (*authenticated and unauthenticated*). With only 2 states then the initial authentication value and branching logic matches one or the other and incorrectly "leaks" out the protected content for a moment or prematurely redirects to a login route.

## Solution

Use an indeterminant `user` value or loading state to indicate to the protected route component that it shouldn't render the protected content or redirect yet.

### Using third indeterminant "state".

For example, if an authenticated `user` value is a user *object* and an unauthenticated `user` value is `null`, then use `undefined` as the indeterminant value and conditionally render null or some loading indicator while the auth state is resolved.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
  redirectPath = '/login',
  children
}) => {
  const { user } = userAuth();

  if (user === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc
  }

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
  }

  return children
    ? children
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

### Using pending/loading "state".

Sometimes it is useful to just add a loading state to the `userAuth` state. The logic is nearly identical.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
  redirectPath = '/login',
  children
}) => {
  const { isLoading, user } = userAuth();

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc
  }

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
  }

  return children
    ? children
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `UserAuth()` does some asynchronous tasks, in which case it's normal you get this behavior. You could use a loading state to show a loader. I assume you could get one from  `UserAuth()` while executing the code for authentication. Like so:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({
    redirectPath = '/login',
    children
}) => {

    const { user, loading } = UserAuth();
    
    if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>

    if (!user) {
        return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace />;
    }

    return children
        ? children
        : <Outlet />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that initially `user` is set to `{}`. Only after about a second or so does it get set to the actual user object.

Comment: Glad I could give a hint @Ben :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to initialize the user object in UserAuth() with null.